# Compute $E[\frac{K}{N+1}]$ and $E[KN]$.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

There are two random variables $K, N$ where $N$ is a non-negative integer and $K$ is ranged from $0$ to $N$. I have a joint distribution $f_{K,N}(k,n) = {n\choose k} p^{n-k}(qq')^kqp'$ for $k \le n$. Also, $p = 1-q$, $p' =1-q'$.

I am asked to compute $E[\frac{K}{N+1}]$ and $E[KN]$.

$$E[\frac{K}{N+1}] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{k}{n+1}f_{K,N}(k,n)= q^2p'q'\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)(p+qq')^{n-1}.$$
The solution shows that the last equation is equal to $$\frac{qq'}{1-qp'}-\frac{q^2p'q'}{(1-qp')^2}\log \frac1{qp'}.$$
I don't quite understand this last step. Especially, where does $\log$ come from?

For $E[KN]$, I found that it is equal to
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n kn f_{K,N}(k,n)=q^2p'q'\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2 (p+qq')^{n-1}.$$

Considering that $E[K] = \frac{q'}{p'}, E[N] = \frac{1-qp'}{qp'}, Cov[K,N] = \frac{q'}{qp'^2}$, $E[KN]$ should be $\frac{2q'-qp'q'}{qp'^2}$. Can you give some hint how to get this result?

Comment: Something wrong here. You have $n-1$ in the denominator and the sum starts with $n=1$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks. I edited it.

Comment: The sum starts from $0$, but later $1$ because the term in the series is zero when $k=0$. Similarly, $1-\frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{n}{n+1} = 0$ when $n=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints: Split your sum into two parts. The first term $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (p+qq')^{n-1}$ is a geometric sum. The second sum is of the form $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {x^{n-1}} {n+1}=\frac  1 {x^{2}} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {x^{n+1}} {n+1}=\frac  1 {x^{2}} \sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac {x^{n}} {n}$. Now the Taylor series for $\log (1-x) $ is $-x-\frac {x^{2}} 2 -\frac {x^{3}} 3-....$. Hence $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac {x^{n}} {n}=-\log (1-x)-x$.